# Вывод чисел из файла

Tags: c++

Мне нужно выводить непостоянное количество данных.
Например в первой строке число 3, тогда из следующей строки нужно вывести 3 числа.
Потом снова например число 4, тогда нужно вывести 4 числа. и т.д.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    const unsigned long long int N = 10000000000;
    unsigned long long int A[n], i, n;
    ifstream infile ("input.txt");
    ofstream outfile("outfile.txt");
    while (infile >> n)
    {
        for ( i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        { 
            getline(A[N]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: только пожалуйста простой код

Comment: Вы прочли 4. В следующей строке **только 4 числа** и больше ничего? Или так, скажем, 5 чисел, какой-то текст, еще числа... Но надо считать только 4 из них? Ставьте **точное ТЗ** - без него результат один: ХЗ...

Comment: Как я понял, структура файла такова: число, обозначающее кол-во данных (целых чисел). Потом эти данные. Потом - все повторяется... по моему, Вам достаточно забыть о getline и вводить все при помощи оператора >>, тогда задача имеет простое решение

Comment: если в первой строке 3 то, в следующей только 3 числа

Answer (score 0):

Предложу "схему кода", о которой я написал в комментарии:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ifstream infile ("input.txt");

    int N, x;

    while ( infile >> N ) {
        for( int i=0; i<N; ++i ){
            infile >> x;
            // что то делаем с x
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

К сожалению, эта схема будет работать только в "олимпиадном" случае, то есть, она рассчитана на правильно сформированные данные: если в строке написано 4, то на следующей строке должно быть ровно 4 числа. Не меньше и не больше.

В первой версии кода я ошибся с .eof(), спасибо за подсказки пользователям EOF и Mikhailo!

Если Ваша зададча заключается в другом - дайте знать, еще что нибудь придумаем!

Comment: а если мне нужно вывести два или более числа одновременно и провести над ними операцию (количество чисел заранее не известно)

Comment: > вывести два или более числа одновременно и провести над ними операцию - я бы предложил тогда дописать код в то место, что "// что то делаем с x" - именно туда поместить обработку данных и вывод результатов.

Comment: Ну засовывайте их в вектор/массив/список...

Comment: `!infile.eof()` - ай ай ай!

Comment: Прошу прощения, решил, что для простого случай сойдет

Comment: Есть же простое решение - `while (infile >> N)`? Зачем эта переменная `eof_rez`?

Comment: Точно. Спасибо! Сейчас поправлю ответ